# configure bidirecctional bridge with mosquitto brokers

Tags: docker-compose, mqtt, load-balancing, mosquitto

I have a load balancer with nginx in port 1885 and two mosquitto containers in ports 1886 and 1887

When I suscribe to port 1885 the petition is sent to one of this two ports so when later I publish in port 1885 the suscribed cliente can see only the messages that the balancer sends to the port the client is, so I can only see half of the total of messages.

To solve this I have to build a bridge between these two ports but because I don't know which port the user suscribed will land on then i need this bridge to be bidirectional.

The problem I encounter is that I created an infinite loop when I publish

this is the configuration of the first container

```
# =================================================================
# Default listener
# =================================================================

# Port to use for the default listener.
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log




#bridges

connection mosquitto2
address mosquitto2:1883
topic test/# both 1
remote_clientid bridge1
try_private true
```

And this is the configuration of the second container

```
# =================================================================
# Default listener
# =================================================================

# Port to use for the default listener.
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log


#bridges

connection mosquitto1
address mosquitto1:1883
topic test/# both 1
remote_clientid bridge2
try_private true
```

Could you tell me please how to avoid this infinite loop? like for example send only if the message comes from port 1885 or something like this.

Comment: What do you think the "both" means in the bridge topic definition?

Comment: I think it means to send all it arrives to this container, and i performed some test so because both have the same config it creates this infinite loop.

But do you know how to have this bidirectional bridge without the infinite loop?

I can make a unidirectional relation between these two containers but it's not valid in my case

Comment: You have 2 bridges, but you don't need 2 bridges if the bridge is bi-directional, so either remove one of the bridge configs or change the `both` to `out`. P.S Mosquitto really is not a good choice if you want to build a HA solution...